# Passing String Type data to .NET PUT WEBAPI through Ajax

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I used to code in this way and it works fine:

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public object Query([FromBody]string sql)
{
    // ...
}
```

Js:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/api/controllerName/query",
    data : "=SELECT * FROM table1",
    dataType : "JSON",
    type : "POST",
    success : function(res){ console.log(res); },
    error : function(req, stat, err){ console.log(stat + ": " + err); }
});
```

So now I do it in the same way for a PUT API, but it doesn't work:

C#:

```
[HttpPut]
public object dispatchProduct(int id, [FromBody]string dispatchStatus = "dispatched")
{
    // ...
}
```

Js

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/auction/dispatchProduct/2",
    type: "PUT",
    data: "=blablabla", 
    dataType: "JSON"
}).done( function createBiditem_doneHandler(result){
    console.log(result);
}).fail( function createBiditem_failHandler(req, stat, err){
    console.log(req);
    console.log(stat);
    console.log(err);
});
```

I got an exception:

> {     "Message": "An error has occurred.",    "ExceptionMessage": "Optional
>   parameter 'dispatchStatus' is not supported by
>   'FormatterParameterBinding'.",    "ExceptionType":
>   "System.InvalidOperationException",   "StackTrace": null }

Could anyone help? I have googled for quite a while, but all the cases are different than mine.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `optional parameters` are fully supported in `WebApi` but not sure `'FormatterParameterBinding` could support it too.

May be you could remove that `optional parameter` and you can do in this way

```
[HttpPut]
public object dispatchProduct(int id, [FromBody]string dispatchStatus)
{
   if (dispatchStatus == null)
   {
        //..works same as before but without a exception
   }
}
```

Comment: You are right, that works now, although I have no idea about 'FormatterParameterBinding'. Thanks!